# How to prevent form submission on wrong button and only work on right button

Tags: reactjs

I've made a codesandbox to showcase the behaviour: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dan-ejyuv

I have two buttons in my form one is forgot password and other is the submit button itself. When I enter values and press enter it registers the forgot password button for no reason even when the submit button has input type="submit". How can I get rid of this behaviour and prevent it to go on the forgot password page but instead it should be submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `type=button` to the `forgot passwrod` button. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) docs for button mentions

`If this attribute is not set, the <button> is associated with its ancestor <form> element, if any.)`

Once you add the `type=button` to the forgot password, it'll not behave as submit button.

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    setForgotPassword(true);
  }}>
  Forgot Password?
</button>
```

[Updated Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wood-n2lrk?file=/src/App.js:1034-1239)

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for unfortunately, I want to be able to press enter after entering form details and submit the form and this is preventing me from doing that.